# Future of Nexus collection for Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch

Will Ubuntu Touch have official updates in the future for Nexus collection or this collection will be forgotten by Canonical?

Answer (score 2):

The Nexus devices are the official development devices for Ubuntu Touch and at least until Ubuntu Touch is sold preinstall on phones, the Nexus collection will be the first devices to get updates. Also Ubuntu uses the the Debian package managing system which allows for constant updates.

Comment: I hope... Because I have bought a Galaxy Nexus just to install Ubuntu Touch, thus I would like to have updates even after public release...